# Symfony, redirectToRoute() with data

Tags: symfony, twig

When I render a twig I can do this:

```
return $this->render('mytwig.html.twig',array("message"=>"Hey"));
```

I'm passing an array with some data that I will use in the twig.

But, I will not render now, I need to use:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('my_route');
```

How can I pass to that route some data? but I don't want to pass an argument with: `redirectToRoute('my_route', array("some"=>"Hey"));` because that's for the URL, I need to use the data in the Twig.

Comment: If the data is not appropriate for the url then stash it in the session.  But this should be an infrequent sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Using your method `redirectToRoute('my_route', array("some"=>"Hey"));` In the controller (or route) you pass the information to, you can use:

```
$some = $request->query->get('some');
```

And then use that variable again when you render render the template like so:

```
return $this->render('mytwig.html.twig',array("some"=> $some ));
```

And then in your twig use:

```
{{some}}
```

Comment: Ok, I think that I'll have to do in another way. Because my twig file is already rendering with some vars, so with this method I will lose all those vars and I will be using only "some"

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. You can use the one parameter and use all other variables as well, just include them when rendering the template.